# Как создать свой виджет или добавить что нибудь в существующий?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

Никак не могу понять как в gtk можно создавать или частично изменять существующий виджет. Если можно, то пример кода хотелось бы.

Comment: [туториал раз](https://www.cc.gatech.edu/data_files/public/doc/gtk/tutorial/gtk_tut-20.html); [туториал2](http://zetcode.com/gui/gtk2/customwidget/); [туториал на русском](https://subscribe.ru/archive/comp.soft.prog.gtk/201004/23072509.html/)

Comment: Это для gtk 2, а надо для gtk 3.

Comment: отличия минимальные (если вообще какие-то будут)...

Comment: они есть, у меня код не собирается с такими примерами.

Comment: [вот](https://paste.pound-python.org/show/H48OvUzVVt2oNxqEzVjJ/) патчик на туториал2. Оба изменения в API описаны [здесь](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch26s02.html).

Comment: спасибо........